# Test run failing on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I tried testing my app using Firebase Test Lab, but it is failing in every case.

This is the error it is showing:-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.raman.snu_exams2-7QBxxpTz9mvJu3y7zUtBQw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.raman.snu_exams2-7QBxxpTz9mvJu3y7zUtBQw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]

I tried installing the multidex dependency but it is still failing all the tests.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error can occur if you're trying to test a debug APK that you built with Android Studio during development.  During development, Gradle may create incremental builds that aren't complete APKs, in order to speed up compilation.  This helps you deploy your app faster for local testing.

For testing on Test Lab, you'll need to build one full APK and upload that.  You can create a whole new, complete APK on the command line with something like this:

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Comment: I made the complete apk using the command given above. Please tell me where it is present now? lIke in which folder?

Comment: Same place as always.